# bringing back android studio's main menu

Tags: android-studio

I accidentally hit the `View>Show main menu` in android studio. Now I cannot bring it back since it is really essential. `Alt+F` shortcut isn't working, and I can't find the shortcut for bringing the main menu back. How can I bring back the main menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Double Tap on shift key .
2. In the pop up window select `Actions`.
3. Type `mainmenu`.
4. The mainmenu will be off , Click on toggle `ON`.

[image: You can see the screenshot below]

Hope this helps..

Comment: certainly it saved me. Thanks. :-)